# Throttle Python smtphandler emails

Tags: python, logging, smtp, postfix-mta

I want to use Python's logger smtphandler to send emails for errors and whatnot.  I also don't want to get my inbox flooded with thousands of emails for the same bug.

Is there a way to throttle the amounts of emails sent?  Ideally, if it keeps catching the same exception, taper off the amount of emails sent.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up making my own wrapper to the SMTPHandler.  First draft so not perfect.  Multiple instances of the handler will limit dupes separately.  Could store self.logged in redis to make it a shared resource.

The only extra parameter that needs to be set is intervals which is a list of minutes (ints). Suppose [0 10 30] is passed in to intervals.  It would say to send an email now.  Subsequent dupes would be ignored until after 10 minutes has passed.  Then subsequent dupes would be ignored until after 30 minutes,.  It won't send any emails after that.

If you want to change what counts as dupe logs, modify _record_type to your requirements.

```
import logging.handlers
import datetime


class SMTPHandler(logging.handlers.SMTPHandler):
    """
    Custom SMTPHandler for the logger.

    You specify the intervals to which emails will be sent.  At most the number
    of emails that will be sent will be equal to the number of intervals set.
    """

    def __init__(self, mailhost, fromaddr, toaddrs, subject, intervals,
                 credentials=None, secure=None, timeout=5.0):
        super(SMTPHandler, self).__init__(mailhost, fromaddr, toaddrs, subject,
                                          credentials, secure, timeout)
        self.logged = {}
        self.init_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.intervals = self._make_intervals(intervals)

    def _make_intervals(self, intervals):
        return [datetime.timedelta(minutes=i) for i in intervals]

    def _record_type(self, record):
        """Make key from LogRecord"""
        type = record.levelname + record.pathname
        if record.exc_info:
            type = type + str(record.exc_info[0])
        return type

    def update(self, record):
        """Check if a similar log has been emitted, if so how many times and has specified interval passed"""
        record_type = self._record_type(record)
        last = self.logged.get(record_type)
        # log if hasn't been logged at all
        if last is None:
            self.logged[record_type] = (1, datetime.datetime.now())
            return True
        # log if last log was more than a specified interval before
        else:
            count, last_date = last
            if count <= len(self.intervals):
                if (last_date - self.init_date) > self.intervals[count]:
                    self.logged[record_type] = (count+1, datetime.datetime.now())
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False

    def emit(self, record):
        emittable = self.update(record)
        if emittable is True:
            super(SMTPHandler, self).emit(record)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [mailinglogger](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mailinglogger/3.8.0) package, it looks like what you need. [This part of documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/mailinglogger/mailinglogger.html#limiting-the-number-of-emails-sent) explains setting limits to protect against flooding. Even without setting anything, it has reasonable default 10 e-mails per hour :)